# It doesnt ask for input, goes straight thru

Tags: java, input, error-handling, custom-error-handling

Its a simple java code, and when i compile it,no errors show up, cumpiling just fine. But when i run it, goes straight thru, doesnt ask for any input or show any output...
Cant tell wy its happening, im a begginer so if somebody can tell me how to get it running...

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Empresa{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int cod, nasc, ingr, atual=2018, i=0;
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(i>3){
            i++;
        System.out.println("Escreva o codigo do funcionario:");
        cod = entrada.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Escreva o ano de nascimento do funcionario:");
        nasc = entrada.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Escreva o ano de ingresso do funcionario:");
        ingr = entrada.nextInt();
        if(((atual-nasc)>=65)||((atual-ingr)>=30)||(((atual-nasc)>=60)&&((atual-ingr)>=25)))
            System.out.println("Requerer aposentadoria");
        else
            System.out.println("Nao requerer");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: can you share your error

Comment: The variable for your loop is initialized to zero, and the condition checks to see if it's greater than three. It's never greater than three, because you increment it _inside_ the loop that it doesn't enter.

Comment: Probably your condition should be `if ((((atual-nasc)>=65)||((atual-ingr)>=30))||(((atual-nasc)>=60)&&((atual-ingr)>=25)))`

Comment: https://imgur.com/5jZCfYK

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Answer (score 1):

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Empresa{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int cod=0, nasc=0, ingr=0, atual=2018, i=0;
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(i<3){
            i++;
        System.out.println("Escreva o codigo do funcionario:");
        cod = entrada.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Escreva o ano de nascimento do funcionario:");
        nasc = entrada.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Escreva o ano de ingresso do funcionario:");
        ingr = entrada.nextInt();
        if(((atual-nasc)>=65)||((atual-ingr)>=30)||(((atual-nasc)>=60)&&((atual-ingr)>=25)))
            System.out.println("Requerer aposentadoria");
        else
            System.out.println("Nao requerer");
    }
}
```

You need to set value for integers and fix your while, if your code wont run again, you should share your error..

Comment: https://imgur.com/5jZCfYK it doesnt show any error, just go straight thru

Comment: Java's primitive type has default value according to Oracle JDK https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score 0):

Wrong logic in while loop. As `i=0` and your loop condition is `i>3` , which will return `false` and loop block wouldn’t be executed. Change the loop condition to `i<3` which will return `true` until `i` is shorter than `3` and loop block will be executed 3 times.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Empresa{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int cod=0, nasc=0, ingr=0, atual=2018, i=0;
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(i<3){
            i++;
        System.out.println("Escreva o codigo do funcionario:");
        cod = entrada.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Escreva o ano de nascimento do funcionario:");
        nasc = entrada.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Escreva o ano de ingresso do funcionario:");
        ingr = entrada.nextInt();
        if(((atual-nasc)>=65)||((atual-ingr)>=30)||(((atual-nasc)>=60)&&((atual-ingr)>=25)))
            System.out.println("Requerer aposentadoria");
        else
            System.out.println("Nao requerer");
    }
}
```